# Java Arraylist clearing : how clear() works

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2D list of objects mypath `List<List<Object>> mypath = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();`. Suppose I have following lines of code

```
  mypath.add(temppath);
  System.out.println("mypath: "+mypath.get(mypath.size()-1));
  temppath.clear();
  System.out.println("mypath: "+mypath.get(mypath.size()-1));
```

I see a list of objects from first print statement, but an empty list from second print. It appears when I clear temppath, that element of mypath also gets cleared. Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Can I clear temppath, without clearing the last element of mypath?

Comment: Add a copy of temppath to mypath instead.

Comment: if I add a copy by doing temppath1=temppath , that doesn't work as well.

Comment: temppath == mypath and therefore you are adding the same list to itself.   You therefore also clear 'both'

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by using List<Object> temppath1 = new ArrayList<Object>(temppath); and adding temppath1 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because both are referring to same `Object` in heap, make it like

```
mypath.add(new ArrayList<Object>(temppath));
```

this will create copy of `temppath`

<sub>if it is not harmful to your app</sub>

Answer (score 5):

When you add temppath to mypath, you don't create a new object, you add a reference to an existing one. Therefore, everything what you do with this object will be reflected in any place where it's referenced.

One possible solution for this problem will be to create a copy of temppath and add it to mypath.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to reuse `temppath` to keep adding new `List` of elements to `mypath`, create a new `List` instance instead of calling `clear()` on it.

```
// temppath.clear();
temppath = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

`List#clear()` does **not** give you a *new* `List` instance and you end up clearing the same list you just added to `mypath`. Only call `clear()` to dispose off elements.

Answer (score 0):

Rivu,

You are clearing temppath, but not removing it from mypath. Hence, on second attempt you are referring to temppath again, which is blank.

if you want to remove temppath use

```
mypath.remove(temppath);
```

instead of

```
temppath.clear();
```